# Prevent Bootstrap Button Invisible Width/Prevent New Line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, spacing

I have two Bootstrap button dropdown menus.  How to I prevent the menus from wrapping to two lines?  I can control the width of the menus with span classes, but the code acts as if there's still more invisible input field which forces the next drop-down menu to the next line.  The even more core problem is that these dropdown inputs force a fixed amount of space between them in the next element to their right, regardless of their actual width.

Ultimately, I want them to behave similarly to input buttons, which align right next to each other.  See screenshot.

[image]

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <!--- BASIC INFO --->
    <div class="span12 well" style="height: 160px; background-color:">
        <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Eye Color">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" placeholder="Hair">
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a>aa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>aa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>aa</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <input class="span4" id="prependedDropdownButton" type="text"  placeholder="Hair">
        </div>
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a>mm</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>mm</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>mm</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <input class="span4" id="prependedDropdownButton" type="text"  placeholder="Hair">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you think you can put a design visual representation of what you want to accomplish? I already have a fiddle here but I keep on reading the question and I don't get completely what you want to do. http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/WPCUd/

Comment: I want the two drop-downs narrower, and to appear side by side.  The spacing should be the same as the spacing between the 'eye color' and 'hair' inputs.  See updated screenshot.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle with all your styles or a link to your site?

Answer (score 0):

After more reading on the Bootstrap documentation and testing I notice that those kind of dropdowns that you want to use suck, they are not responsive. I think you are better off using `<select>` dropdowns.

### Demo

### http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/X8hdg/

### HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="well clearfix">
    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="span3">
        <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Eye Color">
      </div><!--.span3-->

      <div class="span3">
        <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Hair">
      </div><!--.span3-->

      <div class="span3">
        <select class="span12">
          <option>Hair</option>
          <option>Black</option>
          <option>Blonde</option>
        </select>
      </div><!--.span3-->

      <div class="span3">
        <select class="span12">
          <option>Race</option>
          <option>Race 01</option>
          <option>Race 02</option>
        </select>
      </div><!--.span3-->

    </div><!--.row-fluid-->
  </div><!--.well .clearfix-->
</div><!--.row-fluid-->
```

So I guess this is an alternate solution, I cleaned up the code indentation, commenting and what not and divided the spans in a way that I feel would make sense for that kind of responsive menu.

Notice I added clearfix, removed the inline style and the height.

Let me know if this solution is what you expected, otherwise with the other kind of dropdown you want you use it's doable but you will need to hack quite a bit, if it was easy the guys at Twitter Bootstrap would have made that element responsive from the get go.

Cheers.